# How to return JsonResult through generic Func<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, delegates, func

Having an Action that uses a base method that expect a Func

```
public class HomeController: BaseController
{
    public JsonResult HomeController()
    {
        var model =  ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation(() =>
            {
               //do some stuff
            }, LocalResources.CommonErrorMessage);
        return Json(model);
    }
}
```

And the base method that expect Func

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public T ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation<T>(Func<T> actionToExecute, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            return actionToExecute.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
            entry.AddErrorMessage(ex.Message);
            entry.AddErrorMessage(String.Format("Inner Exception:", ex.InnerException.Message));
            //entry.Message = ex.Message;
            entry.Priority = 1;
            entry.EventId = 432;
            entry.Severity = System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error;
            writer.Write(entry);
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = errorMessage });
        }
    }
}
```

It retrieves me an error when I trying to **return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = errorMessage });**

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'T'**

I know that is better if I create an override of `ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation` that expect two action, one to execute/return normally and the second to execute when the operation has an excetion.

Something like this:

```
return ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation(() =>
{
    //do something
    return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = excepciones, TotalRecordCount = excepciones.Count() });
}, () =>
{
    return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = Properties.Resources.CommonErrorMessage });
});
```

But I want to know how to solve the first case:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'T'**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear why your method is generic as you seem to want to always return a `JsonResult` as such simply change your method to this.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation<T>(Func<JsonResult> actionToExecute, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            return actionToExecute.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
            entry.AddErrorMessage(ex.Message);
            entry.AddErrorMessage(String.Format("Inner Exception:", ex.InnerException.Message));
            //entry.Message = ex.Message;
            entry.Priority = 1;
            entry.EventId = 432;
            entry.Severity = System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error;
            writer.Write(entry);
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = errorMessage });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need that to be soo generic. Providing that you will use that only in your actions you can return `ActionResult` as `JsonResult` [derived from it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Think adding [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) of ActionResult will be sufficient in your case:

```
public T ExecuteHandledJTableJsonOperation<T>(Func<T> actionToExecute, string errorMessage) 
    where T: ActionResult
{
    //code
}
```